# Default order changes for same data

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a lookup table and read data from this table. Each row order is import since I generate key via these rows data. So far I have not used order index and I've discovered an interesting bug. It generates key string in different order.

I wonder if it is possible reading order changes for same data when I restart application?

key generator code;

```java
String key = "";
for (SearchUnique unique : searchModel.getConfig().getSearchUniques()) {
    key += "_" + unique.getData();
}
return key;
```

for same data;

first key: _AAA_XYZ_123
second key: _123_XYZ_AAA

Comment: Couldn't you order the result of `getSearchUniques` explicitly to preserve order?

Comment: so far not but i will add order. i would like to figure out underlying reason of the bug.

Comment: What is `getSearchUniques` returning, depending on the implemented type, it can be ordered or not.

Comment: although implementation is not changed, data is not change, data order is changed when application restarted. in first case data order; AAA, XYZ, 123 and in second case 123, XYZ, AAA. is it possible?

Comment: In a relational database, there is no inherent 'order' to rows in a table.  Even a primary key is not an 'ordering' mechanism.  If you need things returned in a specific order you must use the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: so you mean it may return data in different orders at each run  same query for same data?